# Batch insert using groovy Sql?

Tags: jdbc, groovy, batch-processing

How can you do a batch insert using groovy Sql while simulating prepared statements? All the examples I've found are similar to the following and don't use prepared statements.

```
withBatch  { stmt ->
stmt.addBatch("insert into table (field1,field2) values('value1','value2')")
stmt.addBatch("insert into table (field1,field2) values('value3','value4')")
}
```

According to this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3504 there is no way to use prepared statements directly from within batch. What is the best way to simulate this so I can avoid having to write my own code to avoid sql injection?

Answer (score 20):

Groovy 1.8.1 introduced support for prepared statements with batching. Simple example:

```
sql.withBatch(20, """update some_table 
                        set some_column = :newvalue 
                      where id = :key """) { ps ->                 
          mymap.each { k,v ->
              ps.addBatch(key:k, newvalue:v)
          }
}
```

Also see my post on the topic: http://novyden.blogspot.com/2011/09/groovy-batch-prepared-statement-nice.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip! To get this to work for MySQL InnoDB, I had to add "sql.connection.autoCommit = false" before the withBatch, and "sql.connection.commit()" to make it stick.

Comment: How will you do this multiple columns ?

Answer (score 1):

Also related is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4328.

From the above JIRA:

> ...the best we could (simply) do is
> convert such a GString to a normal
> String. For that we could do a little
> bit more than we currently do by
> parsing the String and try to quote or
> escape "string" looking things but not
> number or date looking things but it
> might not be very elegant. Normally we
> would use the "?" character
> placeholders and a prepared statement
> and would have much less to do

In terms of simulating prepared statements, see [Java - escape string to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection)

That being said, you could apply a heuristic from the above and decorate the `withBatch` method

Answer (score 1):

It's supported from version 1.8.1. You can read the [Groovy 1.8.1 release notes](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+1.8.1+release+notes) for details.
Pls check the [API Document](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#withBatch%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) for help.

Answer (score 0):

Owasp ESAPI.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API

Your only option when prepared statements and stored procs are NOT an option, is to manually escape user input.

ESAPI has working, production ready reference methods.

```
Codec ORACLE_CODEC = new OracleCodec();
 String query = "SELECT user_id FROM user_data WHERE user_name = '" + 
   ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL( ORACLE_CODEC, req.getParameter("userID")) + "' and user_password = '"
   + ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL( ORACLE_CODEC, req.getParameter("pwd")) +"'";
```

Source: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Databas