# Replace character in a string

Tags: java, string

```
String username="abc";
String pwd="abc";

String query="Select username,pwd where username = ? and pwd = ?";
```

I want to replace character `'?'` in this string by different values with username and pwd specifed..Is there any function by which we can find `'?'` which is there two times and replace it with username and pwd?

Comment: Is this to send something to a database? If so, you *shouldn't* be performing the replacement yourself. Please provide more context - it's entirely possible that the approach you're trying to take is a really bad idea.

Comment: Is this intented to be an SQL query?May be you should consider using `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, have a look at [`String.replaceFirst`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for instance:

```
String query = "Select username,pwd where username = ? and pwd = ?"
                       .replaceFirst("\\?", username)
                       .replaceFirst("\\?", pwd)
```

Keep in mind though, that you probably want to properly **escape `username` and `pwd`**.

Consider for instance what happens if I provide something like

```
 or 1=1
```

as password.

For more information on this, have a look at the various answers to:

- [Java - escape string to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection)

---

If possible, use `PreparedStatements`!

- [Using Prepared Statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: I dont want to use preparestmt becoz i dont hv control on DB..there is one doubt in this If there will be more parameters like address,emailId then will this work?...is this a dynamic way for replace this?..thanks a lot for giving me prompt reply

Comment: Sure, it will work. Try it out. (But as I said, be sure to escape special characters one way or another :-)

Comment: great..if u can tell more on that..to escape special characters in the same example it will give me a more idea..

Comment: Added a link to my answer. (I'd rather not elaborate on that here, since it's fairly off-topic to the title of your question :-)

Comment: its ok..i will follow that link..it will be helpful me..thanka a lot aioobe..I appreciate your help in this..its solved just within few mins..thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [`String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
String username="abc"; 
String pwd="abc";

String query="Select username,pwd where username = ? and pwd = ?";
query = query.replaceFirst("\\?", username);
query = query.replaceFirst("\\?", pwd);
```

but if you are doing this for an actual db-query you will want to use prepared statements:
eg.

```
String username="abc"; 
String pwd="abc";

String query="Select username,pwd where username = ? and pwd = ?";
PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
pStmt.setParameter(1, username);
pStmt.setParameter(2, pwd);

ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

OT regarding String replacement, but If you are planning to use SQL with JDBC have a look at `PreparedStatement` that does this for you and prevents SQL injection.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 0):

you ca use `string.format` for this scenario 
i.e

`query = String.format(query,username,pwd);`

use `%s` instead of `?`