# Stop sql injection

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-injection

how to prevent sql injection 
i am using below code to login

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "");

Statement  statement = con.createStatement();

ResultSet  rs= statement.executeQuery("SELECT email,pass FROM db_pass where email='" + email + "'and pass='" + password + "'"    );

if (rs.next()) {

    String a=rs.getString(1);
    String b=rs.getString(2);
    rs.close();
```

it's work fine but when it put (nitin' OR '1'='1) the user is get access without putting valid password

Comment: it's working sql query buddy....

Comment: @zero0cool - no space is required at that point.  (Sure, it makes it more readable ... but is anyone actually reading is?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent SQL injection attacks in a Java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516625/prevent-sql-injection-attacks-in-a-java-program) ... and many others.

Answer (score 7):

Use `PreparedStatement`. You can find an example in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

To prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) all queries should be parametrized and
String concatenation should never be used to create dynamic SQL.

Comment: +1 - If you use SQL directly from Java (via JDBC), this is definitely the best ... and simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to use an ORM (object relational mapper). ORMs typically have built-in defenses against SQL injections.

Another great way to prevent sql injections is to use a white list (i.e. a list of acceptable user inputs). When you receive input from a user, check to see if it is in the white list; if it isn't reject it.

In your case, you want to have a white list of possible usernames and a white list of possible password; you can describe a white list of usernames and a white list of passwords using Regular Expressions. Don't homebrew your own Regular Expression though, there are plenty of pre-built Regular Expressions available online. You don't want to make your own because it's easy to make a mistake in its formulation that makes it vulnerable to SQL injection.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: yup it helps me ... thanx mike

Answer (score -1):

A typical and easy way to do this would be to compare the results of a hashing operation (md5 or sha1). The query would then look like

```
SELECT email, pass from db_pass where md5(email)='" + md5(email) + "' and md5(pass)='" + md5(password) + "'"
```

However, this would mean that you have an md5 function available in the language you are developing this and your DB-System has a md5 function available too (for example, mysql does).  Note that this does not make SQL injection completely impossible but is a good basic protection against the example you give.

Comment: Bad idea.  You protect yourself from injection, but at the cost of making many queries impossible.  For instance, you wouldn't be able to do a `LIKE` query to check for `"...@yahoo.com"` email addresses.

Answer (score -1):

you need to convert your string , if your string is abc' you should give the string abc'' to sql if your string is in like ''.