# How do I select a specific string from an SQL database?

Tags: android, sql, database, select

I've spent some hours on trying to solve this but the only answer I get is that I can't select from a string? Is that so? How do I do it otherwise? Here's my code:

public String getHotness(String l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    String[] columns = new String []{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null); 
    int iHotness = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOTNESS);

    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String hotness = c.getString(iHotness);
        return hotness;
    }


    return null;
}
```

Where l is a name of a person in my database. How would I select and get information from this person by his name?

Thanks! You guys are the best!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select only records that fit a specific criteria using the WHERE clause for the select. In case of [`SQLiteDatabase#query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method, you need to use the third parameter.

Other considerations:

- You should use parameters instead of concatenating the values to avoid common issues (like SQL injections).
- No need to check if returned `Cursor` is null, it never is (as the documentation also states).
- Also you should close your `Cursor` before returning from the method.

Example:

```
final String theName = "The person name";
Cursor c = null;
try {
    c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + " = ?", new String[]{theName}, null, null, null); 
    if (c.moveToNext()) {
        // Do your stuff
    }
} finally {
   if (c != null) {
       c.close();
   }
}`
```

Note that previous query will only match rows where `KEY_NAME` column is **exactly** `theName` value. If you want to search by names that include `theName` value, you need to use `LIKE` operator instead.

```
final String likeName = "%" + theName + "%";
final Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + " LIKE ?", new String[]{likeName}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Wait, what do you mean with "You should use parameters instead of concatenating the values to avoid common issues (like SQL injections)."?

Comment: I mean this: `KEY_ROWID + "=" + l` has security vulnerabilities, while this `KEY_NAME + " = ?"` hasn't (at least not in your code).

Comment: You can check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516625/prevent-sql-injection-attacks-in-a-java-program) for more details.

Comment: Why is that? I've not come so far yet

Comment: I've added a link in previous comment for more details about SQL parameters, check it out.

Comment: Ok it works now, I don't really know why since I don't understand what "SelectionArgs" does.

Comment: Glad it's working. I already provided a link explaining SQL arguments 2 comments above. Here it is again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516625/prevent-sql-injection-attacks-in-a-java-program

Comment: Hey dude, I guess I'm just stupid. I'll comeback and thank you when I can understand what that link says!

Comment: No, nobody is born with knowledge, but you're definitely a little blind ;) Good luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

LIKE is what you are looking for. % means anything BEFORE yourname is matching. ?yourname means only 1 char before. if you make sure that the name matches exactly you will need to use name = 'yourname' instead.

```
Cursor c = null;
try {
c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * from yourtable where name LIKE '%yourname%', null);
if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0 && c.moveToFirst()) {
   do {  
     c.getString(....);
   } while (c.moveToNext());
}
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
finally { 
 if (c != null) c.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Uselessly complicated. It's `Cursor`, `c` is never null, you don't need the `if`, and no need `do/while`. Also question never said it needs LIKE operator.

Comment: No, it's not. Check my updated answer why you should validate this.

Comment: Yes it is. Check my comment again: c is never null, you don't need the if, and no need do/while. I won't downvote because it is correct (somehow).