# UCASE and UPPER sql functions

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11gr2

I am trying to do the following query:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE UCASE(LAST_NAME) ";
query += "LIKE '" + lastName.toUpperCase() + "%'";
```

in an example of usage of an servlet to access to a database
But I am getting the error message:

```
Excepcion java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "UCASE": invalid identifier
```

On the other hand, when I use the UPPER sql function, the example works but the results do not show the values of the LASTNAME column in uppercase. I do not understand what happens.

Comment: What if `lastName` will be `'; DROP DATABASE ...;--`?

Comment: The database will be dropped, though only if the user using the application has the privilege to do that.
@lad2025 is implying that you should sanitize your input before using that in a sql firing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just comparing the upper case values, but you're selecting the actual values with `select *`

Comment: Ok. But what happens with the UCASE function?

Comment: As far as I know UCASE is not a valid function on Oracle (or SQL Server, which you have also tagged)

Comment: I am using Oracle Database, 11g Release 2 (11.2) and I have found the following sql compatibility table: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/gateways.112/e12014/dev_apps.htm#CHDIEFEB But I am a newbie with databases and I do not understand the compability of UPPER and UCASE in this table.

Comment: Did you read what it says above the table? `Table 4-1 describes how Oracle database and the gateway handle SQL functions for a DB2 UDB for z/OS`. If you're not using anything like that, just use UPPER, it's the correct function.

Answer (score 1):

to get the uppercase name in your resultset you need to use UPPER in your select list, not UCASE, like this:

```
String query = "SELECT UPPER(LAST_NAME) AS UPPERNAME, * FROM EMP WHERE UPPER(LAST_NAME) ";
query += "LIKE '" + lastName.toUpperCase() + "%'";
```

What your code is doing here is building a query string named `query`. Once `query` is complete, it will be sent to the database for parsing and running.

When you are building a query to the database, you have to use the built-in database functions for the part of the query that the database is going to parse and run. So, in your example, Java is doing `toUpperCase` on `lastName` and then putting that literal into the query string that will go to the database. `UPPER(LAST_NAME)` is going into the query string as is, it will get passed to the database just like that and run by the database. So it needs to be a function that the database can parse and run: an Oracle function, not a Java function.

Answer (score 1):

[UCASE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_ucase.html) is a DB2 function & not Oracle. For Oracle, you need to use `UPPER` .

Second part of your question is already answered by James Z.

Having said that, I am answering because previous answers didn't pointed out SQL injection problem with the way you listed your query.

Make it a habit to always execute parametrized queries with jdbc & not by directly appending values to query string.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE UCASE(LAST_NAME) LIKE ? ";
```

Your parameter would be - `lastName.toUpperCase()+"%"`

[SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516625/prevent-sql-injection-attacks-in-a-java-program)