# setOnEditCommit with Iteration JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview

Im a pure newbie. I made my table by adding the columns from database with iteration:

```
public void captureDataSuper() {
    Connection c;
    ObservableList<ObservableList> data;
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        c = KonekDB.createConnection();
        //SQL FOR SELECTING ALL OF CUSTOMER
        String SQL = "SELECT * from adminsupervisor";
        //ResultSet
        ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

        /**
         * ********************************
         * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY * ********************************
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            //now its editable
            col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Adminsupervisor>forTableColumn());
            //trying to make effect on database after edited with setOnEditCommit
            col.setOnEditCommit(
                    new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Adminsupervisor, String>>() {

                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Adminsupervisor, String> t) {
                    ((Adminsupervisor) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())).set(j, t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
            );
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });

            supervisorTable.getColumns().addAll(col);
            System.out.println("Column [" + i + "] ");
        }

        /**
         * ******************************
         * Data added to ObservableList * ******************************
         */
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                //Iterate Column
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Row [1] added " + row);
            data.add(row);

        }

        //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
        supervisorTable.setItems(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
    }
    }
```

As you can see, my setOnEditCommit was completely non sense:

```
   col.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Adminsupervisor, String>>() {

            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Adminsupervisor, String> t) {
                ((Adminsupervisor) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).set(j, t.getNewValue());
            }
        }
        );
```

This is the model class Adminsupervisor:

```
public class Adminsupervisor {

private String id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String userType;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getUserType() {
    return userType;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void setUserType(String userType) {
    this.userType = userType;
}

void set(int j, String newValue) {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            setId(newValue);
        }
        if (j == 2) {
            setPassword(newValue);
        }
        if (j == 3) {
            setUserType(newValue);
        }
        if (j == 1) {
            setUsername(newValue);
        }
    }
    try {
        Connection c = KonekDB.createConnection();

        String SQL = "UPDATE adminsupervisor SET "
                + "username=" + username + ","
                + "password=" + password + ","
                + "userType=" + userType + " WHERE id=" + id + "";
        //ResultSet
        c.createStatement().executeUpdate(SQL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
    }
}}
```

I got this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper cannot be cast to AdminSide.Adminsupervisor
at AdminSide.PanelAdmin$1.handle(PanelAdmin.java:275)
at AdminSide.PanelAdmin$1.handle(PanelAdmin.java:272)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.commitEdit(TableCell.java:349)
at javafx.scene.control.cell.CellUtils.lambda$createTextField$615(CellUtils.java:248)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.fire(TextFieldBehavior.java:179)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:178)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:127)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(BehaviorBase.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:197)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:147)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:227)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So my cell wouldnt do anything after edit commited.

Comment: Have a look at your StackTrace and the first line saying, that you try to cast "ObservableListWrapper" to your modell class "AdminSide.Adminsupervisor". Are you sure, that your DATA object is an ObservableList of an ObservableList or do you want to have an ObservableList of AdminSide.Adminsupervisor? `ObservableList<AdminSide.Adminsupervisor>`?

Comment: @SSchuette yes I want to make Adminsupervisor be the same type as ObservableList so I can wrap it without problem. Would you kindly tell me what to do?

Comment: "I want to make `Adminsupervisor` the same type as `ObservableList`"? These are (very) different types - you can't just pretend they are the same thing. You need to decide what type is represented by each row of the table, and stick to it. If you want it to be `Adminsupervisor`, then make `data` an `ObservableList<Adminsupervisor>` and add the appropriate objects to it. If you want it to be `ObservableList` (should be `ObservableList<String>`) then remove the `Adminsupervisor` class entirely and just work with `ObservableList`. The first one is better, imho, but you need to choose one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is declared as `ObservableList<ObservableList> data;` and you fill it with `ObservableList`s:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    //Iterate Row
    ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ...
    data.add(row);
}
```

In the `onEditCommit` handler you do this however:

```
public void handle(CellEditEvent<Adminsupervisor, String> t) {
    ((Adminsupervisor) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
            t.getTablePosition().getRow())).set(j, t.getNewValue());
}
```

`t.getTableView().getItems().get(index)` returns a `ObservableList`, which you try to cast to `Adminsupervisor` which for obvious reasons doesn't work...

You need to use the same type for items and in the handler. Whether you want to use `ObservableList` or `Adminsupervisor` is up to you...

**Note:** Add type parameters to the `TableView` and the `TableColumn`, and the compiler should complain about this. By using raw types however, you prevent the compiler from doing those checks (you may get a warning about raw types though).

Furthermore

```
for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
        setId(newValue);
    }
    if (j == 2) {
        setPassword(newValue);
    }
    if (j == 3) {
        setUserType(newValue);
    }
    if (j == 1) {
        setUsername(newValue);
    }
}
```

should be rewrittern as

```
setId(newValue);
setUsername(newValue);
setPassword(newValue);
setUserType(newValue);

j = 4; // not really neccessary since there is no read access to j
```

At least that achieves the same effect. (But maybe you just added the `for` loop around those `if`s for no reason and it should be removed.)

And also consider removing `j` as parameter from the `Adminsupervisor.set` method since the value is never used in method (in the original version it's overwritten with `0` before any read access happens in `for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)` and in the improved version it's not read at all).

Furthermore the `ObservableValue` returned by your `cellValueFactory` will never trigger an update. If you use `ObservableList` as item type, you could use the `Bindings` class to get a `ObservableValue` for a specific index:

```
col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
        return Bindings.stringValueAt(param.getValue(), j);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks mister, but i need solution not judgement.

Comment: @SuryaHardiansyah: Then simply add `Adminsupervisor`s as items or alternatively cast to `ObservableList` instead.  I thought this would be pretty obvious once the issue is explained...

Comment: how to do it mister? :"(
please kindly tell me the code that i should insert between

Comment: +1 for the "Note". Do not use raw types: if a type is generic, you should always parametrize it. That way the compiler will catch the errors before you try to run. Compile time errors are much easier to fix. Decide what type is represented by each row (is each row an `Adminsupervisor` or an `ObservableList`??), and specify it in the code with `TableView<Adminsupervisor>` or `TableView<ObservableList<...>>` as appropriate.