# How can I only get 1 element from a SQL Database?

Tags: java, sql

I have a small problem. I wrote a method in which I have an SQL query that should output a correct string after 2 parameters. When debugging, however, the result is not the right element. I don't know why this happens.

```
public static String findRightTemplate(String user_name, int template_id)
  throws Exception {


        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();

        st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(
          "SELECT template FROM templates " +
          "where template_id=template_id AND user_name=user_name"
          );

        String temp="";
        while(rs.next())
        {
            temp=rs.getString("template");
        }


        rs.close();
        st.close();
        conn.close();
```

I ask for the username and template_id and I just want to get an element out of the template column.
The SQL query is correct. I've already tested that. But it seems that the query runs through all elements with the same username. As a result, I only get the last element and not the right one.

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: Is this a generic JDBC question, or specific to one database engine? The latter (use `LIMIT`) is far more optimal than the former (reading all rows, discarding most of them).

Comment: Your SQL server will see the following query: `SELECT template FROM templates where template_id=template_id AND user_name=user_name` Your `WHERE` condition will **always** be true (well... with the exception of NULL).

Comment: Its specific. I tryed with LIMIT but. But as result i got the first element from the User

Comment: "As a result, I only get the last element and not the right one." -- This doesn't make sense. Relational tables do not have inherent row ordering; in the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause the query can return the rows in any order, and this can also change over time.

Comment: Use `PreparedStaement` and parametrize your query.

Comment: @ The Impaler i want not a row as result.

Comment: @Doncarlito87 `SELECT` statements return "result sets" composed of rows and columns. What are you expecting?

Comment: You better show the sample data, and the expected result. I'm voting to close this question, since it's not well formulated.

Comment: You should be using prepared statements, but for a quick fix it may be enough to change `user_name=user_name"` to `user_name = '" + user_name + "'"`

Comment: @SteveLovell Why do you even suggest that?

Comment: I added my table now. Wie man sehen kann. gibt es 4 Spalten. Id, template (String) username und template_id

Comment: @Steve Lovell I tried your solution but I still get the wrong template

Comment: Ok Problem Solved. "SELECT template FROM templates WHERE template_id='" + template_id + "' AND user_name = '" + user_name + "'" was right. Thx a lot

Comment: Please, please tell me that this isn't production code, then.  Assembling your query string like that leaves you wide open to [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516625/prevent-sql-injection-attacks-in-a-java-program). (Obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/))

Comment: No its not. Dont worry

Comment: @stevecross, your answer is much better than my "hack". However, the dangers of SQL injection are often overstated. We do not know the context in which this code is being used or how the variables are populated. My comment also has the virtue of hinting why the code from the OP didn't work.

Comment: @SteveLovell That may be true sometimes but I would argue that there are no downsides when using a `PreparedStatement`. In my opinion one should understand the risks of SQL injections before he can decide if building a query 'by hand ' is okay. And I don't think that this is the case here.

Comment: You make a good point @stevecross.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you do not use the method parameters inside your query. As already suggested you should use a `PreparedStatement` to fix that. You should basically do the following:

```
public static String findRightTemplate(String userName, int templateId) throws SQLException {
    try (final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("...")) {
        final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT template " +
                "FROM templates " +
                "WHERE user_name = ? " +
                "AND template_id = ? " +
                "LIMIT 1"
        );

        preparedStatement.setString(1, userName);
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, templateId);

        final ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        if (resultSet.next()) {
            return resultSet.getString(1);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

If you do not use a `PreparedStatement` and build the query manually as suggested in the comments your application could be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: 1 and 2 are swiapped. And connection, preparedStatement and resultSet should be `close()`d. Best with `try (Connection connection = ...) {` etcetera.

Comment: Thanks, good catch! You are absolutely right, but in favor of a simpler example I left out the JDBC boilerplate. Personally I would not even use JDBC directly but something like Spring's JDBCTemplate.