# Secure doGet parameter in Servlet

Tags: java, php, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm doing a simple register form and I need to pass some parmeters in url, however I'm concerned about the security in java. in  PHP I used to use

```
mysql_escape_string
```

To make sure no special characters is passed to the variable. however I'm not sure if thats needed in Java.

the question is : is it safe to use **request.getAttribute(arg0)** directly or do I need to secure it using some special method ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - escape string to prevent SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an answer to that question in [Java - escape string to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection).

I believe that the best thing to do is not to encode your command as a string, but to use a PreparedSatements and set the parameter using its methods, like SetInteger, SetBoolean as so on.

Comment: Ok thanks. will do so, just I want to make sure we wont get hacked because of something stupid I do ..

Comment: Prepared statements instead of escaping is indeed the way to go. That also applies to PHP btw (mysqli and PDO support them)

Comment: I also found this class for escaping string http://wiki.vnetpublishing.com/Java_Mysql_Real_Escape_String

Comment: It is an interesting class, but I believe that it goes a long way to do the same thing that PreparedStatements and its methods does a lot better. One thing that I learned during my years at developing is that reinventing the wheel usually results in a poorer wheel.