# ORA-01861: literal doesn't match format string

Tags: java, sql, date, jdbc

In my application I passed date value (as string) as parameter to Servlet. In Servlet code, I converted the string to sql date as "2013-02-05" (yyyy-MM-dd).

Example: **dat="05/02/2013"** converted to **sqlDate="2013-02-05"**.
My servlet code is

```
 dat= request.getParameter("dat");
 //dat="05/02/2013";
     try
     {
         java.util.Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").parse(dat);
         //out.println(date);
         sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
         //out.println(sqlDate);
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {

     }

if(div_code!=null)
{
try
{

 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
 java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxx:pdsm", "test", "test");
 Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("insert into offer1 values('"+r_code+"','"+v_name+"','"+vcode+"','"+div_code+"','"+sec_code+"','"+extent+"','"+phone+"','"+sqlDate+"','"+loan+"','"+seeds+"','"+offerno+"','"+loc+"')");
      conn.setAutoCommit(true);
      out.println("data inserted");

   }catch(Exception e)
    {
       out.println(e);
    }
 }
```

When I'm calling this from android application, it shows error as **"ORA-01861: literal doesn't match format string**". The format I've used is shown correct result when I tested with sample input. But data didn't get inserted.

What is the problem in my code? Why am I receiving this error? Do I need to convert further? If yes, then how?

Also, someone explain can I use pl/sql function (to_date()) in servlet? Because it is easy to convert date

Edit: Modified Code:

```
String query="insert into offer1('RCODE','OFFERNO','DAT') values(?,?,?)"; 
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1,r_code);
ps.setString(2,offerno);
ps.setDate(3,sqlDate);
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
out.println("data inserted");
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: What do you mean dd/MM/yyyy? which date?

Comment: on Line #5, 05/02/2013 format should be `dd/MM/yyyy`, not `dd/MM/yy`

Comment: If not, then how it display the sql date as correct format

Comment: see @V.J. answer, line#5 is for parsing string `05/02/2013` to Date, for the desired result, you can use another `SimpleDateFormat` for formatting Date to String.

Comment: I don't need to format it to string. I've store date as database

Comment: Please use the `[servlets]` tag only when you have a concrete problem related to `javax.servlet.*` classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't frame your query like this (appending everything into a single string).

It is vulnerable to SQL injection See [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

So better use `PreparedStatement` as it will protect you from SQL injection and your conversion tasks for various values will be automatically taken care of.

So if you have a `java.sql.Date` variable `sqlDate` and now you want to insert it in the database: then you need these simple steps:

```
String query = "insert into your_table_name(`name`,`myDate`) values(?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
//now just set the values like this
ps.setString(1,"ABC");
//note index starts at 1
ps.setDate(2,sqlDate);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Now hope you can figure out how to do it for yourself.

For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection) and [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/508823/JDBC/databases/prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: I think it will be useful. I'll try now

Comment: how did you frame the query string?

Comment: try this query `insert into offer1(\`RCODE\`,\`OFFERNO\`,\`DAT\`) values(?,?,?)` Notice the backticks (`\``) for the column name

Comment: I tried this. insert into offer1(RCODE,OFFENO,DAT). Work well

Answer (score 0):

```
//String date = "05/02/2013";
dat= request.getParameter("dat");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date testDate = null;
try {
    testDate = dateFormater.parse(dat);
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

From "dd/MM/yyyy" to "yyyy/MM/dd"

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String convertedDate = formatter.format(testDate);
System.out.println("Your converted Date :- "+convertedDate);
```

Comment: I've already converted by line #5 and #7. Why I'm receiving error when inserting the date to database?

Comment: I don't need to format it to string. I've store date as database

Answer (score 0):

I can see several problems in your code

1) remove Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"), DriverManager knows how to find the necessary driver on the classpath

2) use conn.prepareStatement, see API

3) remove conn.setAutoCommit(true); conn is in autocommit mode by default

4) use stmt.executeUpdate instead of stmt.executeQuery