# MySQL syntax error when string input contains quotation marks

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

When I submitted the form to my JDBC connection page it gives an error.
I submitted the form with a data like this

```
It's wrong
```

It gives an error as shown below

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's wrong' IN BOOLEAN MODE) and bot2=1' at line 1

My code is

```
       String Query="SELECT * FROM ques WHERE MATCH(subject) AGAINST('"+vv+"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  and bot2=1";
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306                   /wst","manohar","manohar");
       stmt=conn.prepareStatement(Query);
       rs=stmt.executeQuery(Query);
       while(rs.next())
         {
            ....
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```java
String Query="SELECT * FROM ques WHERE MATCH(subject) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)  and bot2=1";
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wst","manohar","manohar");
stmt=conn.prepareStatement(Query);
stmt.setString(1, vv);
rs=stmt.executeQuery();
```

The technique is called a "parameterized query" and it offers several advantages, one of which is that you don't have to worry about escaping special characters in string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you are not escaping the string in your query.

I think you could find this thread usefull: [Java - escape string to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection)