# MySQL Statement error in JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have an issue with an sql statement and i dont know how to handle it. Here is the problem:

```
query = "INSERT INTO `mmr`(`userID`, `RunningProjects`, `MainOrders`) VALUES ("
                        + session.getAttribute("id")
                        + ",'"
                        + request.getParameter("RunningProjects")
                        + "','"
                        + request.getParameter("MainOrders")')";
```

The values are obtained from the `post` form which contains free text. The problem is, whenever a user enters characters like `'`, i will get an error because that tells the compiler that the value is over here(i suppose) and now look for the next value. I don't know how to include these characters and send them to database without having an error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - escape string to prevent SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Are there no prepared statements in JSP ? Obviously the quotations are wrong.

Comment: Understood! Thanks all for the quick response :) Much appreciated!

Comment: Read more about [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Move your code in Servlet. **Don't** mix business and database logic with presentation logic.

Comment: Newbie and i'm no a short deadline. I need to read and understand more. Java, JSP, servlets... all pretty confusing right now. But i have to save my job right now :( and understand as time goes on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character `'` is used to surround literals in `MySQL`. And if any data contains such character as part of it, we have to escape it. This can be done using *Prepared Statement* in `Java`.

Change your query code accordingly.

```
query = "INSERT INTO `mmr`(`userID`, `RunningProjects`, `MainOrders`) 
         VALUES ( ?, ?,? )";
```

Now define a `PreparedStatement` instance and use it to bind values.

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement( query );
pst.setString( 1, session.getAttribute("id") );
pst.setString( 2, request.getParameter("RunningProjects") );
pst.setString( 3, request.getParameter("MainOrders") );

int result = pst.executeUpdate();
```

And, I suggest use of beans to handle business logic.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
query = "INSERT INTO `mmr`(`userID`, `RunningProjects`, `MainOrders`) VALUES ("
                        + session.getAttribute("id")
                        + ",'"
                        + request.getParameter("RunningProjects")
                        + "','"
                        + request.getParameter("MainOrders")
                        + "')";
```

Comment: I made that error while copying here. The quotings were fine annd it worked until the user typed something string that could spoild the sql statement. Thanks for the correction though. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using normal statement in your JDBC code. Instead, I would suggest you to use **Prepared statement**. Prepared statement is generally used to eliminate this kind of problem and caching issue. If you will use prepared statement I think your problem will be solved

Comment: okay.try using prepared statement.post here if face any issue

Comment: 'ps.setInt(1, session.getAttribute("id"));' getting error: The method setInt(int, int) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, Object)

Comment: type cast session.getAttribute("id") with int or use parseInt to convert. because session.getAttribute(String) will always return an object. So you need to explicitly manage it according to your need