# The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, jsp-tags

```
 public void adduser(UserBean user) throws SQLException{
   String query = "INSERT INTO usersInformation ( username, " + 
     "password, email ) VALUES ( '" + user.getUsername() + "', '" + 
     user.getPassword() + "', '" + user.getEmail() + "' )" ;
   statement.execute(query);
}
```

I get this exception in this line : statement.execute(query)
 Can anyone helps  me ? 
Exception : was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL140525011235350' defined on 'USERSINFORMATION'.

[EDITED]

This is my bean class

```
public class UserBean {

private String username;
private String password;
private String email;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

index.jsp ( Mail part of index.jsp )

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <jsp:useBean id = "userbean" class = "newpackage.UserBean"  />
 <jsp:useBean id = "userdatabean" class = "newpackage.UserDataBean" />

     <jsp:setProperty name ="userbean" property="*"/>
        <% userdatabean.adduser(userbean); %>
```

Comment: Not going to solve the current problem, but you're currently open to [SQL Injection](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-can-i-explain-sql-injection-without-technical-jargon) (depending on how account login/recovery is written, I can get you to email me the contents of your database).  You need to be using [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1812891), period.

Comment: Thank you so much . I am a beginner and these are my first SQL Code :)

Answer (score 1):

From the exception details it's clear that the statement is entering duplicate value in primary key field, thus violating unique key constraint. Check your data and insert accordingly

Comment: I checked it ! But I don't see any problem.This exception occurs when I run the index.jsp !Any Idea ?  Thank's.

Comment: Then the datamodel is needed to check further

Comment: So What should I do ?

Comment: Share your regarding datamodel with data here