# Too few parameters. Expected 1. error

Tags: java, ms-access

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

This is the error I am getting when I execute this query:

```
s="select * from package where p_name like "+packageChange;
```

when I execute:

```
s="select * from package";
```

then it works fine.

But whats the problem with "p_name" column of table "package"...?

My code,

```
res=start.executeQuery("select * from package where p_name like "+packageChange);
```

the statement

```
System.out.println("ddddddd="+packageChange);
```

prints ddddddd=pkg5

Comment: What's the value of `packageChange`?

Comment: it is the package name we want to change to... selected from drop down list (JComboBox)

Comment: I meant what value is the variable getting? Can you attempt to print it out and share the result?

Comment: @Mureinik see my edition in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this Java code? If so, use bind variables:

```
Connection conn = ...;
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("select * from package where p_name like ?");
st.setString(1, packageChange);
res = st.executeQuery();
```

Otherwise, you are subject for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

In your original code, enclose the parameter in apostrophes:

```
res=start.executeQuery("select * from package where p_name like '"+packageChange + "'");
```

But I encourage you **not to do this**: you should check for apostrophes and newlines (and maybe more) in the `packageChange` variable - sanitize it, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1812891/952135).