# How to Modify record of table with geoTools

Tags: java, openlayers, postgis, geotools

I'm developing a GIS application with **java**. I am using **Spring RESTController** and **GeoTools**. In client side(I use `Openlayers 2.13.1`), user **modifies a feature of wfs layer** and want to update it in server side. After modifying, user send the request as follow:

```
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <wfs:Update typeName="feature:itsme" xmlns:feature="http://iran.me">
        <wfs:Property>
            <wfs:Name>the_geom</wfs:Name>
            <wfs:Value>
                <gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326">
                    <gml:pos>49.02405689339376 34.858924130844805</gml:pos>
                </gml:Point>
            </wfs:Value>
        </wfs:Property>
        <wfs:Property>
            <wfs:Name>name</wfs:Name>
            <wfs:Value>Salam Bar Hossein</wfs:Value>
        </wfs:Property>
        <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:FeatureId fid="point.3"/>
        </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

In server side I want to parse this request and modify the record of table(I use postgis).

**How do I parse xml?**
***How do I modify the record of table?***

Comment: What java-framework do you use? Does it use java-hibernate? If yes, you might be interested in: http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/03-dialects/02-postgis/

Comment: I use hibernate and hibernate-spatial, but I nead my features be GeoTools Objects

Answer (score 0):

> How do I parse xml?

There are plenty xml-parsers for java available. [SAX-based](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/sax-example.html), [DOM-based](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html)...

> How do I modify the record of table?

Well, that depends.

- Do you use hibernate, or a framework that uses hibernate? There are spatial solutions for it, just look at [this link](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/03-dialects/02-postgis/) for example.
- Do you use raw SQL-processing? Then you will have to build a SQL-querystring ("INSERT INTO ...") on your server, and pump your data into your database. You have to take care of proper SQL-escapting to [prevent injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection).

Comment: I use hibernate and hibernate-spatial, but I nead my features be GeoTools Objects. How can I merge **Hibernate-spatial** with **GeoTools**