# fetch records with apostrophe in mysql using LIKE query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-like, apostrophe

I have MYSQL query like this

```
String query="select DISTINCT sctName from snomedicd10map where sctName Like '" + search + "%" + "' LIMIT 5 ";
```

this query is for auto complete and if i search word like code's , girl's etc during typing of Apostrophe(') null point exception is occurred

how can i overcome from this . when user enters name with Apostrophe(') in text field it should fetch the result .

i have fetching result from mysql database .

How can i achieve this.

Comment: You can use `"` instead of `'`, you can escape them (like this `\'`), or you can make your query much safer by making it a parameterized one, and passing the string with `%` appended on the end as the parameter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1812920/4421474  Try to use prepared statements as a best practice

Comment: @Uueerdo i tried to change and its showing same error will u change above query like that

Comment: I'm not strongly familiar with Java, the escape sequence I provided may be wrong (as Himalay's answer below would suggest).

Comment: You should really use a prepared statement and set the parameter through the prepared statement, then you don't need to escape yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you have the name hard coded you can repeat and escape

```
Select * from Students where name like 'John O''Neal'
```

If you are taking them **sanitize the string or use paramaterized queries.** Look into prepared statements.

Comment: i didnt hard code the name and value in the column contains like that and i cant change every name into like that and in 1000 values are there

Comment: There should be some replace function available to you in Java that will allow you to replace `'` with `''` in your `search` variable. Something _similar to_ `search = replace(search, "'", "''") + "%";` should give you a usable search variable.

Comment: @teachme Actually, disregard the above, the time to replace `'` with `''` would have been needed before this point (otherwise `'` would not be in the search variable).

Comment: @Uueerdo thankx man . i have changed into prepared statement and its working fine .

Comment: @Uueerdo That is bad advice, the OP should be using a PreparedStatement instead of mangling values themselves.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that was my first advice in my initial comment to the question; but due to various circumstances using them may not always be feasible, so...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `PreparedStatement`, so it will handle the escaping for you. For example:

```
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = Connection.prepareStatement("select DISTINCT sctName from snomedicd10map where sctName Like concat(?, '%') LIMIT 5") {
    pstmt.setString(1, search);
    try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
        // process result
    }
}
```

Alternatively (handle wildcard in code):

```
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = Connection.prepareStatement("select DISTINCT sctName from snomedicd10map where sctName Like ? LIMIT 5") {
    pstmt.setString(1, search + "%");
    try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
        // process result
    }
}
```

The JDBC driver will automatically handle escaping (or send the parameters in a way that does not require escaping)

Comment: yes i have done like this only later and thank you for your valuable answer .

Comment: Does the `||` in `sctName Like ? || '%'` do something special in Java? Because I don't think that works, equivalent to the original query, in MySQL.

Comment: That is the SQL standard string concatenation, maybe MySQL uses `+` instead.

Comment: I pretty much always use MySQL's `CONCAT(item1, item2, ...)` function; it always messes me up in MSSQL since SSMS doesn't warn me until I've made 10 such statements and have to go change them back to `+` expressions. _(Edit: just confirmed both `+` and `||` used on two strings in MySQL yield `0`... because it converts them both to numbers. For example, `'a' + '12b'` would give `12`.)_ ...MSSQL doesn't seem to like `||` either.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit to reflect that once I am at a real computer.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I was suggesting in my original comment, is it what you tried?

```
String query="select DISTINCT sctName from snomedicd10map where sctName Like '" 
            + search.replaceAll("'", "\'") + "%' LIMIT 5 ";
```

Comment: That is bad advice, the OP should be using a PreparedStatement instead of mangling values themselves.