# How to restrict hibernate Criteria.list() from executing DDL queries

Tags: hibernate

There is a possible sql injection scenario where I am executing

```
query = currentHibernateSession.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
```

then i am using `query.list()` to execute the query.

Now even though DML queries like DELETE do not work, but DDL queries like drop table go through even though i can see an exception.

A temporary fix would be to parse the sql queries and avoid the DML and DDL queries but i was wondering if there is better way to prevent sql injection in this scenario.

Comment: See accepted answer in this SO -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: @aksappy The solution is feasible only if we know what query we are executing, but in cases where we can have different select queries to execute based on the request i dont think this method will help

Comment: I suggest you make a list of dynamic queries that can get executed with this method, how many of them pose a risk and then work towards a solution? Prepared Statements still is the best approach to go, AFAIK.