# How to write single quote in h:inputTextarea?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

In a page i have a multiple text boxes , where users can enter any sort of data.

I used `h:inputTextarea` tag.

JSP/JSF:

```
<h:inputTextarea style="width:100%" value="#{abc.remark}"  id="remarks" />
```

Java:

```
  public String getRemark() {
        return remark;
    }

    public void setRemark(String remark) {
        this.remark= remark;
    }
```

and

```
insert into table1 ('Remarks','Other') values (this.getRemark() + "','"+this.getOther());
```

It works almost, but whenever user tries to enter single quote in remarks like

> John's income is Good

it breaks down and throws java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917: missing comma.

Query Screenshot from log:

[image]

Need resolution.

Comment: As you can see, your issue  is not java, jsf, jsf or richtextarea related (you could have known since it correctly arrives on the server from your client). Inserting in the database fails...

Comment: Its not a duplicate.. how do you explain the users to enter John''s income is good?

Comment: That's not the solution. You should replace ' with '' in the values before inserting them.

Comment: Other solution is to use parameters: [Java - escape string to prevent SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Use StringEscapeUtils.escapeSQL method, it will do the needful

Comment: @NehaShettar That is extremely bad advice, people should not be using escaping kludges, the should be using prepared statements with parameters.