# When checking in the database, the output is repeating / looping

Tags: java, jdbc

I only clicked the button once, but the output is 2. I wonder if there is something wrong with my condition in the while loop? Or should I use a different approach?

As you can see in the picture, I entered only one data, but the output, executes the conditions in
if and else;

```
String pass = PF.getText();
        String user = TF.getText();
        Connection con = connect.getConnection();

        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;

        String query = "SELECT username, password FROM users";

        try{         
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()){
                if(user.equals(rs.getString(("username")))){
                    if(pass.equals(rs.getString(("password")))){
                        System.out.println("Logged In!");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Error");
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Not in the database!");
                }
            }
            st.close();
```

[image: Here is the Sample Output]

Comment: use `where` clause

Comment: You are lacking any checks in `SELECT username, password FROM users` It should be something like `SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username= ? AND password =?` , then bind username and password to the prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks man, I have used the WHERE clause and I'm not that good in database sql, so maybe that's one of the problem I did not notice. -_-

Comment: I hope you realize that in a real application, you should not store the password as plaintext, but that instead you should hash it with a suitable password hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your table, you have two rows. And, you execute following query, it will return two rows.

```
 String query = "SELECT username, password FROM users";
```

You could add username and password in `where` clause instead.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT username, password FROM users where username =? AND password=?");
stmt.setString(1, userid);
stmt.setString(2, pass);
```

Better use `PreparedStatement` to avoid any sql injection.

Comment: Agreed. I gave an example for OP understanding.

Comment: I have corrected now. I hope this will be appropriate answer. ;)

Comment: Don't argue guys, I have tried this approach, and it works for me, so thank you for your help everyone. :) I believe there are other approach for this, but this one I understand easily.

Answer (score 1):

In below line you are selecting all the rows in `users` table

```
String query = "SELECT username, password FROM users";
```

You need to limit it to specific one that you want using `WHERE` clause.

> Wikipedia about `WHERE` clause:
>
> WHERE clauses are not mandatory clauses of SQL DML statements, but can
>   be used to limit the number of rows affected by a SQL DML statement or
>   returned by a query. In brief SQL WHERE clause is used to extract only
>   those results from a SQL statement, such as: SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE,
>   or DELETE statement.

Like below:

```
String query = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '"+yourVariable+"' password = '"+yourVariable+"'";
```

I did this using `String` concatenation. This will lead to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). So you can use `PreparedStatement` as @Ravi mentioned.

> [Oracle doc. about `PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):
>
> A SQL statement is precompiled and stored in a `PreparedStatement`
>   object. This object can then be used to efficiently execute this
>   statement multiple times.

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection) may help you.