# Error creating bean with name Controller: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-annotations, spring-4

I am trying to upgrade to my hibernate version 3.2 to 4.1.0 and at the same time integrating with spring 4.3.10, I thought I have configured well but When I run my application I am getting following exception. can someone solve my issue, I am not getting what mistake I am doing.

> stack trace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scmController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'scm_service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scmServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'scmdao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scmDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'datasource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [DRSCM1] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [DRSCM1].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [DRSCM1] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [DRSCM1].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [DRSCM1] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [DRSCM1].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [DRSCM1] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [DRSCM1].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> Lib :

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
apache-logging-log4j.jar
asm-5.1.jar
axis.jar
com.springsource.javax.jms-1.1.0.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-discovery-0.2.jar
commons-email-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar
commons-io-1.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.2-javadoc.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dumbster-1.6.jar
gson-2.2.3.jar
gwtx-1.5.0.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
icu4j-4.8.1.jar
itext-2.1.7.jar
itextpdf-5.4.3.jar
jackson-annotations-2.8.10.jar
jackson-core-2.8.10.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jasperreports-3.7.6.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
jaxrpc.jar
jboss-jmx-4.2.2.GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
jboss-system-4.0.2.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
jsp-api-2.2.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
jxl-2.6.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
lucene-core-2.3.2.jar
lucene-highlighter-2.0.0.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar
persistence-api-1.0.jar
poi-3.6.jar
postgresql-9.3-1104-jdbc4.jar
quartz-1.5.2.jar
saaj.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
wsdl4j.jar
xom-1.0.jar
```

> dispatcher-servlet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.nic.scm" />
     <context:annotation-config />
     <mvc:annotation-driven /> 
     <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"  />

     <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" /> 

       <!--  <mvc:cache-control max-age="3600" cache-public="true"/> -->

     <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


 <jee:jndi-lookup id="datasource" jndi-name="java:/DRSCM1" resource-ref="true"/> 


     <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">scm</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                </prop>


                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

     <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>


</beans>
```

> Dao:

```
public interface scmDao {

    List<Users> getUser(String username);
}
```

> Implemetation:

```
@Repository
public class scmDaoImpl implements scmDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    @Transactional

    public List<Users> getUser(String username){

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();       
        List<Users> user_list = new ArrayList<Users>();


        String sql= " select uc_user_id,uc_password,uc_user_name,role as role_name,cast(role_id as int) as role_id, "
                + "u.office_code,off.office_name_en,off.district_code,dc.dist_name_en "
                + "from users u inner join office_code off on u.office_code=off.office_code "
                + "inner join  user_role ur on u.uc_user_id=ur.user_id inner join roles r on ur.ur_role_id=r.role_id "
                + "left join  district_code dc on dc.dist_code = off.district_code "
                + "where u.uc_user_name='"+username+"' ";


        try{

            Query qry = session.createSQLQuery(sql);        
            user_list = qry.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Users.class)).list(); 

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return user_list;

    }
}
```

> Service:

```
public interface scmService {

    List<Users> getUser(String username);

}
```

> ServiceImple:

```
@Service
public class scmServiceImpl implements scmService {


    @Autowired
    private scmDao scmdao;

    public scmDao getScmdao() {
        return scmdao;
    }

    public void setScmdao(scmDao scmdao) {
        this.scmdao = scmdao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> getUser(String username) {   
        return scmdao.getUser(username);
    }
}
```

> Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ScmController {


    @Autowired
    private scmService scm_service;

    public scmService getScm_service() {
        return scm_service;
    }

    public void setScm_service(scmService scm_service) {
        this.scm_service = scm_service;
    }

    HttpSession session;

    public HttpSession getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(HttpSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @RequestMapping("login")
    public String forwardToRegistration(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Users user = new Users();
        model.addAttribute("loginmodel", user);
        return "login";
    }
```

Comment: `String sql = ...  + "where u.uc_user_name='"+username+"' "; ` never do that (string concat of queries with user input). It is sql injection waiting to happen : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection . Also you have a service layer... open the transaction there rather than in your dao layer.