# How to resolve the error "Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'type_id' at row 1"?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

```
Statement s_add_purchase_wedding= conn.createStatement();
String sql_add_purchase_wedding = "INSERT INTO bidservice(token_id,added_id,purchase_id,service_type,type_id,bid_amount,forward_status,confirmation)VALUES"
        + "('"+url_id+"','"+added_id+"','"+purchase_id+"','"+pur_wed.getTypeWedding()+"',1,'"+pur_wed.getAmount()+"','"+pur_wed.getForwardAdmin()+"'"
        + ",'"+pur_wed.getConfirmation()+"')";

s_add_purchase_wedding.executeUpdate(sql_add_purchase_wedding);
```

I already declared `url_id`, `added_id` and `puchase_id  and assign values to them.

Comment: You should read [escape string to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the insertion of an Integer(1) into the table( +"',1,'"). The best way of inserting an Integer would be ("',"+1+",").

How about when you do it this way?

```sql
String sql_add_purchase_wedding = "INSERT INTO bidservice(token_id, added_id, purchase_id, service_type, type_id, bid_amount, forward_status, confirmation) VALUES ("+
                    "'"+ url_id+"',"+
                    "'"+ added_id+"',"+
                    "'"+ purchase_id+"',"+
                    "'"+ pur_wed.getTypeWedding() +"',"+
                    1 +","+
                    "'"+ pur_wed.getAmount()+"',"+
                    "'"+ pur_wed.getForwardAdmin()+"',"+
                    "'"+ pur_wed.getConfirmation()+"'"+
                ")";

s_add_purchase_wedding.executeUpdate(sql_add_purchase_wedding);
```